# Swift: UIIamgeView not keeping an aspect ration of 1:1 on iPad (the rectangle it gets stretched)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have created an imageView which works perfectly fine on iPhone. It set to be a square (aspect ratio of 1:1), but on iPad the whole thing doesn't behave the way it should be.

The user can load an image from the library. The ImagePicker is set to allow editing and shows the square outline of the imageView (so that the user can position the image accordingly to the 1:1 aspect ration of the image view.

On iPad the imageView and the picker behave different. Instead of showing a square in which the user can position the image in it now shows a rectangle filling the whole iPad screen (see images below). And the image inside the imageView is presented as the whole image with black bars.

Another strange behavior is that when the user saves the new imageView on iPhone it is saved as a square (as shown), but on iPad it is not saved as a square, but as the whole image (but I want everything that is not shown to be clipped).

Is there a way to cut of everything outside the squared imageView?

This is how the images are presented in the UIImagePicker:

[image]

As you can see on the left the outline uses the whole iPad screen and apparently this is how the image is loaded although the imageView itself is a square. On the right the iPhone picker shows clearly just the square outline. And this is how I want to use the picker on iPad as well.

Update: I have updated the app with the popover UIImagePicker as suggested, but as you can see it still shows in the windows the same rectangle like outline compared to the iPhone with the squared outline.

Or in other words: how to use the imageView (with an aspect ratio of 1:1) on iPad? Am I missing a setting to set the picker to just get a squared image?

This is all I do for now with he picker and again on iPhone it works perfectly.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self

        if let popoverPicker = picker.popoverPresentationController {
            presenter.sourceView = imageView
        }
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ok, so is there really an `UIImageView` that you manage, or is everything controlled by `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` should be presented using a popover controller on iPad if the `sourceType` is Photo Library or Saved Photos Album, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller Point 4.

Comment: moreover it seems to me that the image aspects are the same for both screenshot, the only difference is in screen aspect ratio

Comment: It doesn't look like it's the image picker - at least primarily. (1) Set `.allowEditing` to false and see what happens with the elected image. If you see differences your app is the place to look. (2) I've seen this picker behavior pretty much everywhere - so take an image that is not square (1:1) and see how it looks in the picker with `.allow editing = false`. I'm betting you'll see a 1:1 image. (3) If both of these work well, the issue is with trying to "edit" a non-square image through `UIImagePicker`, which - I believe - is it's "behavior".

Comment: I have updated the question (see above) with a new image showing the popover UIImagePicker. It still shows the same rectangle like outline.

Comment: @dfd Setting picker.allowsEditiing = false doesn't work at all. No image is loaded (which might be the popover presentation - I have never used a popover before and I just updated the code like you can see above). Maybe there is the problem? If not what did you mean with "the app is the place to look"?

Comment: I must be missing something. First, my logic... (1) A "stock" `UIImagePicker` works as full screen portrait-only on iPhone and as a popup in iPad, (2) is used to select an image from either the camera or library given the proper privacy info.plist keys - iOS 10+ - and (3) is presented from another view controller. That view controller is set to be the picker's delegate and uses `imagePickerController(didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) to retrieve what the user selected.

Comment: Little of this jibes with what I'm seeing in your question. The images suggest you are presenting a single image - maybe that is part of using `.allowEditing = true` but my experience with that is that (a) it's very buggy and (b) the image is shown in a template or overlay like you have in your iPhone screen shot. And... **NOW** I'm getting it. Or at least *some* of your issue! It's the canned behavior of trying to set `.allowEditing = true` that always made me shy away from using it. :-) But stripping away the editing... your question asked about 1:1 aspect.

Comment: I found that, while in Photos a non-square image appears as `.scaleAspectFit` in the picker, in my apps it *does not*. I also never found a setting to make is such. My original comment was meant to ask you to *separate* the *two* issues I read in your question - (1) how a non-square image appears in the picker and (2) having the editing set in your picker. By stating "the app is the place to look" I meant that if the picker is displaying a 3:2 image as 1:1 you probably cannot change that, but if the image returned is displayed as 1:1 *outside* of the picker look elsewhere. Anyways, good luck.